# Kubernetes: Interactive Rails Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Rails server running with both a `web` and `worker` Deployment. One starts Puma, the other Sidekiq. How can I connect to an interactive `rails console` using my application's image running on my Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to to use `kubectl exec -ti <container> -- bash`. From there bring up your rails console.

You might also need to add `-li` for bash. That will give you a shell in the container.

It's possible to run various commands directly without the use of bash. You just need to make sure to use `-ti` for the exec command so that you can interact with it.

For more details see

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/getting-into-containers/